# Generating basic OAuth header

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, oauth

I am trying to understand how to POST data using the TradeKing API, which uses the OAuth library. After speaking to an API support specialist, he explained that the only thing missing is an OAuth header which is required to complete the request.

My experience with OAuth is very limited and there is not one `POST` PHP example in the official documentation. I appreciate any help on how to successfully generate an OAuth header suitable for the API.

I tried feeding off the example in the following URL in my code below, however, it seems it is depreciated and all of the built in functions used in the example are missing in the latest version:

https://gist.github.com/JCBarry/2853042

Thanks in advance!

Official `POST` Documentation

https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/accounts-id-orders-post

This is what I tried:

```
    <?php
      // Your keys/secrets for access
      $consumer_key     = '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661';
      $consumer_secret  = 'ff2513194e75315625628304c9eb66e8';
      $access_token     = '150a96573adf12b21dab621e85497e6e';
      $access_secret    = '5c7b57d450a71d378a5eda991f809e56';

      $oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
        $oauth->disableSSLChecks(); 
        $oauth->setToken($access_token,$access_secret);


        $url = 'https://api.tradeking.com/v1/accounts/12345678/orders/preview.xml';
        $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <FIXML xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
        <Order TmInForce="0" Typ="1" Side="1" Acct="12345678">
        <Instrmt SecTyp="CS" Sym="F"/>
        <OrdQty Qty="1"/>
        </Order>
        </FIXML>';


        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
    ?>
```

This is the error I am getting:

`Error AuthenticationFailure signature_method_rejected /v1/accounts/12345678/orders/preview.xml`

Comment: When you run this, what happens?

Comment: @halfer, The PHP code is just a base example of how to use the API, it just pulls basic account information about the user based on the API keys provided. The PHP code needs to be adjusted to perform the stock order, by somehow using the XML code in the 'example request'. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: The docs look excellent to me, but the second bit of code you've supplied is the doc's generic "PHP example", and not related to placing orders at all. I'd recommend getting the example working first - I expect they have a sandbox you can play in. I'm not familiar with OAuth, but I should think everything is ReSTful - I'd try some PHP ReST/HTTP libraries, starting with Pest or Guzzle.

Comment: (In my experience, you don't generally generate the XML yourself - that's the job of a Rest library).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Getting the placing order example working is exactly what I am having trouble doing. They don't have a sandbox and they don't have any PHP examples other than the one I posted. For this reason, I feel documentation is poor.

Comment: Each to their own, I suppose! I can't say since I've not tried it, but it looks pretty straightforward. Not having a test environment isn't great though. Just [found this example](https://gist.github.com/JCBarry/2853042), maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, that code is depreciated and many of the built in functions are no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API you need to send an Authorization header that looks like this

```
/*
Authorization: OAuth
  oauth_consumer_key="672e71387c0a126f4e13296ecfb2b7bc",
  oauth_nonce="cfdb7f42de425d94fbc24c11a920c33e",
  oauth_signature="Vfm148kAgBZ6azEHqds43aY2UsEg3D",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="1306871932",
  oauth_token="819682555b63ab8bd90a4138138e7365",
  oauth_version="1.0"
*/
```

Try the code below. You'll need to define `$oauth_nonce` and `$oauth_signature`.

```
$header = [
    "Authorization: OAuth \n" .
    'oauth_consumer_key="'.$consumer_key.'"' . " \n" .
    'oauth_nonce="'.$oauth_nonce.'"' .  " \n" .
    'oauth_signature="'.$oauth_signature.'"' . " \n" .
    'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"' . " \n" .
    'oauth_timestamp="'.time().'"' . " \n" .
    'oauth_token="'.$access_token.'"' . " \n" .
    'oauth_version="1.0"'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Answer (score 1):

Their API looks pretty well documented, I have problems to understand your question then.

For example in [*Request Structure*](https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/request-structure):

> **Headers**
>
> For authenticated calls we require that you send over a valid [OAuth](https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/oauth) header. For unauthenticated requests, there aren't any required headers.

In the code-example you give, these headers are *totally* missing with the HTTP request you fire with `curl_exec()`. so your example is not going to work at all, if it would *that* would be wondering.

However wondering is that you first use the [**OAuth** extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.oauth.php) but then you use the [Curl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php). That are two different concepts. They do not magically work together.

So for me it most likely looks like you're still undecided on what you actually want to program (by the line) and I suggest you throw away the code so far as it is only standing in your own way.

Just start from scratch with doing research first about what OAuth is, which Oauth und HTTP client library you want to use and how to consume this OAuth based API you've referenced in your question. As the API you're trying to use is pretty well documented, I'm sure you should be able to ask a concrete programming question in no time that should be much less ambigous and therefore easy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, first you have to get your oauth token. Here's a working code to do that:

```
// Change this! Use the right values!
$consumer_key     = '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661';
$consumer_secret  = 'ff2513194e75315625628304c9eb66e8';
$access_token     = '150a96573adf12b21dab621e85497e6e';
$access_secret    = '5c7b57d450a71d378a5eda991f809e56';

try {
    $oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret);
    $oauth->setToken($access_token,$access_secret);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken("https://developers.tradeking.com/oauth/request_token");
    if(!empty($access_token_info)) {
        print_r($access_token_info);
    } else {                       
        print "Failed fetching access token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse();
    }
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
    echo "Response: ". $E->lastResponse . "\n";
```

If all is ok, you'll have a response like this:

```
Array
(
    [oauth_token] => some_token
    [oauth_token_secret] => some_token_secret
    [...extra data here...]

)
```

With this info, you can set up the required OAuth headers before making the curl request:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $header = [...]; // Fill this array with info store in $access_token_info variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
```